# How can I track down a runaway php script?

Tags: php, logging, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla site which occasionally (every day or 3) will 'run away' and drive the VPS processor load sky high. It's a managed server and my hosting company is being very helpful but so far we can't track it down.
I suspect it's not a Joomla problem but one of my custom extra scripts but I'd welcome advice on how to track down which.
Usually, when the problem strikes, the overload is such that I can't even access the server and have to wait till the hosting company kills it and restarts. 
There is nothing untoward in the Joomla error_log or in the php logs.
If you do catch the runaway processes, it's always...

> /usr/bin/php /home/phouse/public_html/index.php

...which doesn't narrow it down much as it's just the main Joomla home page!
It seems database related as the MySQL process goes mad at the same time.

Anyone suggest any other logging or anything else I can try to track this down?
It's a live site so there are some limitations on what I can try!

Thanks

Comment: you could try mod_status, which'd let you see what each apache child is doing. if you can catch the server while it's in runaway mode, you'd at least get an idea of what the runaway child's inputs (e.g. method + query parameters) are at the time it's happening.

Comment: Sounds very much like a MySQL query. I'd begin by looking for joins. Hopefully you are doing full joins on two (or more) large tables.